# How to separate html code from css code

Tags: html, css

I have a file containing both html and css code.How it is possible to separate the html code in some files and css in some other files??

Comment: You're right, that a good practice to split :
* HTML is what I want to show
* CSS is how I want to show it
* Javascript is how I interact with it

Comment: Refer http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can save the css in a `.css` file. Then in your HTML head tags, you can do `<link rel='stylesheet' href='yourcssfile.css'>`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='yourcssfile.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Test</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

In `yourcssfile.css`

```
p {
  color:red;
}
```

This will make the paragraph text red and your CSS is within a different file.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the CSS code into a `file.css` and include it in your HTML file.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file.css">
</head>
```